# How can i ignore some files into a local repository synched with github?

Tags: git, github

i'm using github to create a copy of the latest version of my code in a local machine, i don't want to make push requests i just want to make pull requests and modify some files in my local machine and try to say to github to ignore some files and update the other files.

I use the following command to ignore a file named "config.inc.php":

```
git rm /home/escogit/www/inc/config.inc.php
```

Then i made changes to other files in the remote github repository and when i try to get the new changes with the command "git pull" i get the following error:

```
remote: Counting objects: 9, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 4), reused 5 (delta 4)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From github.com:Visooal/Colegios
   e724ba3..a624059  master     -> origin/master
Updating e724ba3..a624059
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
www/inc/config.inc.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Note: even if i commit with the command git commit -m ".config.inc.php ignored" i get that error

Answer (score 1):

First, `git rm` does not ignore a file. It removes the file locally and from the index. If you committed the file before you removed it, it will always be in your tree, even if it's not in the current index. Another person can easily re-add it by accident. You should setup a .gitignore entry for that file after you `git rm` it. People can still manually bypass .gitignore but the file won't show up in `git status` or any UI tools anymore.

You need to do what it says. `git commit -a -m "My Commit Comment"` before you do `git pull`

Just to give a clearer picture, run these commands assuming you already `git rm`'ed that file.

```
echo 'config.inc.php' > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -a -m "Removed uneeded file"
git pull
// Fix any merge issues
git commit -a -m "Merge"
git push
```

Comment: 'git rm' does a lot more than just make 'Git stop tracking it' - deleting the file being the most serious.  'git rm --cached' removes it from the index but Git is still 'tracking it' as it exists in the source and will be seen by 'git status' and the like.

Comment: @GoZoner I deleted my previous comment as it was confusing as I was confused as to the point of your comment. You are right, if he wants to keep the file on his local system but remove it from his git index he should use `git rm --cached`.

Answer (score 0):

Git won't allow you to pull with uncommitted changes. To make git ignore files usually you would make a `.gitignore` file, but you can't here because that would be a change; but you can add the file names to `repo/.git/info/exclude`. This file uses the same syntax as .gitignore but is not committed or seen by the git index. So in your example you would add the line

```
www/inc/config.inc.php
```

To `escogit/.git/info/exclude`.

You may still have a problem if you change one of these ignored files on the remote and then pull that change. So the best thing to do is commit the local changes. They're not going to be pushed anyway so it doesn't matter. To do this run

```
git commit -a -m "a message explaining commit"
```

Then you can pull and git will automatically merge the changes for you. If you need to get the local back to a clean state you can do this with `git checkout .`

Comment: Why would him making a change be bad? He can create, add and modify anything he wants. Git is just preventing you from modifying untracked files with tracked files. As long as he commits before the pull he is fine.

Comment: id edited the file and the git commit -a -m "sample" output the following message:Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From github.com:Visooal/Colegios
   a624059..db091a4  master     -> origin/master
Updating a624059..db091a4
Fast-forward
 www/inc/config.inc.php |    2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-). So it syncronized the file

Comment: The problem I refer to is if one uses the local ignoring method to avoid git complaining. Committing the change and then pulling is the correct method (and then never pushing). Is it working to your satisfaction now gustavomanolo?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore a file, then ignore changes under .gitignore.

so it would be something like this:
Add your file to **.gitignore**:

`echo '/home/escogit/www/inc/config.inc.php' >> .gitignore`

then ignore changes in **gitignore**:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged .gitignore`

And it's DONE!!

**warning:** all local changes in .gitignore are going to be omitted to undo this action, and re-undo it again with desired features use:
`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged .gitignore`